# Removing the titlebar while using slick2d?

Tags: java, interface, slick

I recently started using slick2D in my gaming programs and a problem I have is not having the ability to remove the border/titlebar. I usually do this to create my own cutom look/ interface but if I try:

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

It doesnt work.

How do you acheive this?

Comment: Did you try setundecorated(true)??

Comment: sorry i meant to write true @Savlon but where do i put this?

Comment: I believe this has to be set before the window is created. So you'll need to create a launcher or somehow relaunch the existing window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I was using

```
AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Game());
```

to create my game. However I wanted to set the frame to be undecorated. So I searched around and found that if you changed

```
AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new WizardGame());
```

to

```
CanvasGameContainerapp = new CanvasGameContainer(new Game());
```

so that its now a canvas and then add it to a JFrame and set that JFrame to undecorated, you would get a undecorated slick2D program.

CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    CanvasGameContainer app = new CanvasGameContainer(new Game());
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(app);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    app.start();
}
```

The only problem that i have with it is that i have to click it once to render the images. If i don't it just has a black screen. This could be because of my other code but I don't think it should happen for anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so here is a basic application that has the title bar removed

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Without Title Bar Frame");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

**Paste the above code into a java class**

**Also be sure to import**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

You see how frame.setUndecorated(true); is straight after the instantiation of the frame?
Place yours in the same place and you will have no issue at all :)

EDIT: here is what I found which may work.

http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4978

http://codebrocken.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/java-creating-undecorated-window-with.html?m=1

But as it states in that post it isn't support yet.

Comment: this would work if i wasnt using slick2D but I am so it won't work because I'm not creating a JFrame

Comment: Hmm I see... So you are using Display to create your window? You can't create a full screen app? Have the surrounding areas of your window black? I'm not sure if Display has a setUndecorated method.. You may have to look through the slick2D API

Comment: i can create a full screen app (I just need to change false to true in this code : "app.setDisplayMode(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, false);"

Comment: I found something that may work... Check my answer again